# Graphics DrawImage causes error with big red X

Tags: c#, windows, graphics, bitmap, drawimage

I have a collection of bitmap images that I am looping through and writing them all to one new bitmap. Basically I am taking a loose collection of bitmaps and writing them all to one bitmap one after another so that they are visible as one image.

When i call dc.DrawImage from one of the bitmaps in the collection onto the new bitmap my winform is showing a big red X in the form. When I set a PictureBox.Image to the newly drawn bitmap I am getting a big red X.

For some reason i cannot find the error anywhere. I am not able to locate the error with debugging.

Now, if I just set the PictureBox.Image to one of the images in the collection of images with-out looping and drawning onto a new bitmap everything works fine.

To make everything ease I am only working with one bitmap that is in the collection and drawing the one bitmap to the new bitmap. So I know I have only one bitmap to get working then i can add the other ones.

In the images below is what the form looks like if i just set the picturebox.image of the image in the collection.
The second image is the error that shows after I loop and drawing the bitmap in the collection to another bitmap.

The code below is what needs to work, but throws an error.

Notice where I am setting the property of the PictureBox.Image like so: 
this.picBx.Image = schedule; this causes the error.

But if i set the picturebox.image like so:

this.picBx.Image = schedules[0].Door; it works just fine.

```
  DoorSchedules schedules = GetDoorDrawing(elev, projInfo.ProjectName);
            int prevWidth = 0;
            //
            using (Bitmap schedule = new Bitmap(schedules.Width + 50, schedules.Height + 50))
            {
                using (Graphics dc = Graphics.FromImage(schedule))
                {
                    using (Pen pen = new Pen(LINE_COLOR))
                    {
                        pen.Width = 4;
                        pen.Color =
                            Color.FromArgb(50, LINE_COLOR.R, LINE_COLOR.G, LINE_COLOR.B);
                        //
                        for (byte i = 0; i < schedules.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (i > 0)
                            {
                                dc.DrawLine(pen, prevWidth - 25, 0,
                                                 prevWidth - 25, schedule.Height);
                            };

                            dc.DrawImage(schedules[i].Door, prevWidth, 0);

                            prevWidth += schedules[i].Door.Width;
                        };
                    };
                };
                this.picBx.Image = schedule;
                this.picBx.BackColor = BACK_COLOR;
                this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(schedule.Width, schedule.Height);
            };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `Bitmap schedule` defined in a using statement.

When that using block ends, the bitmap is disposed.

Comment: I'm setting the pricturebox.image property before I leave the using statement.

Comment: Doesn't matter.  You aren't assigning a separate copy of the bitmap to picturebox.image - both picturebox.image and schedule refer to the same object, which gets disposed.